# impossible ton access to my phone Android studio

Tags: android, windows-8, usb

*

### Windows 8| Android version 4.4.2  |trouble for connection

Hi,

i would like to run an app on my device but i can't acces to it by usb. I have tried to use adb directly in android studio with the command:

```
abd devices -l .
```

Unfortunately, it show me an empty list of device.

i 've also installed google usb driver but it make no differences.

Nevertheless, something disturb me:

When i connect my phone to my computer , i can't find any notification about the connection of the phone, and i can't access to my device in the windows file manager too.

a)Does it mean that my device is not recognize by my computer?

b)What could be the missing step that i should perform to get access to my device?
does somebody have a solution ?

Comment: try another computer/phone/cable, maybe some of that is broken.

Comment: Make sure you have enabled your device to communicate via adb. You need to enable "developer mode" on the device. You should also be asked, in a popup on your device, whether to accept a usb connection to your dev machine. If you haven't done either of these, adb won't work.

Comment: i 've tryed with 3 different cables but it doesn't work. If i use a friend's phone , it can detect the usb connection ( and so i see the notification). 
That step doesn't happened when i connect my phone.
i've  enabled developer mode. however , i have neither popup asking me for accepting usb connection, nor notification .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps to enable communication between your phone and Android Studio.

1. Open Settings -> About on your Android phone or tablet.
2. If you have a Samsung Galaxy S4, Note 8.0, Tab 3  or any other Galaxy device with Android 4.2, open Settings> More tab> About and tap it.
3. If you have Galaxy Note 3 or any Galaxy device with Android 4.3, go to Galaxy Note 3 from Settings> General> About and tap the Build version 7 times.
   Now scroll to Build number and tap it 7  times.
4. After tapping the Build Number 7 times, you will see a message “You are now a developer!” If you have a Galaxy S4 or any other Samsung Galaxy device with Android 4.2, the message reads as follows- “Developer mode has been enabled”.
5. Return to the main Settings menu and now you’ll be able to see Developer Options.
6. Tap on Developer options and mark the box in front of  USB Debugging  to enable it.
7. To disable USB Debugging mode later, you can uncheck the box before the option
   To enable Developer Options, go to Settings> Developer options and tap on the ON/OFF slider on the top of the page.